# extract coefficients from more than one linear regression model with multiple terms in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, regression, lm

I am trying to generate a data frame of intercepts and coefficients for multiple different linear regression models generated from subsets of a data set. I cannot share my data unfortunately but I can explain it using the mtcars set. I am creating a regression model predicting mpg from cyl, hp, and wt for each value of carb.
After digging around for a while, I found many examples that do what I want but only for a model with 1 predictor (like mpg~wt). It all falls apart when I add the other terms. This is what I have based my work so far on:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/extract-slopes-by-group-broom-dplyr/2751/8
[Efficient way to extract coefficients from many linear regression lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56195604/efficient-way-to-extract-coefficients-from-many-linear-regression-lines)

This is what I have tried

```
library(tidyverse);library(broom)
df <- mtcars
tryme <- df %>%
  split(.$carb)%>%
  map(~lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt,data=.x)) %>%
  map_df(tidy)
```

with this result

```
    term            estimate    std.error   statistic   p.value
1   (Intercept) 46.034633   7.68430306  5.99073626  9.31E-03
2   cyl         2.650503624 4.14371413  0.63964442  5.68E-01
3   hp          -0.230007961    0.1573354   -1.46189576 2.40E-01
4   wt          -5.231999683    9.23136027  -0.56676368 6.11E-01
5   (Intercept) 39.84451509 2.95537984  13.48202845 1.03E-05
6   cyl         -0.846094229    0.93995084  -0.90014732 4.03E-01
7   hp          -0.007452737    0.03998485  -0.18638901 8.58E-01
8   wt          -4.133340298    1.42757472  -2.89535829 2.75E-02
9   (Intercept) 17.50267062 22.13706712 0.79064993  5.74E-01
10  cyl         NA          NA          NA          NA
11  hp          NA          NA          NA          NA
12  wt          -0.3115727  5.73067255  -0.05436931 9.65E-01
13  (Intercept) 45.33390978 12.93999647 3.50339429  1.28E-02
14  cyl         -4.195214198    3.492613    -1.20116778 2.75E-01
15  hp          0.029361878 0.04927895  0.59583008  5.73E-01
16  wt          -1.239041102    1.03937377  -1.19210349 2.78E-01
17  (Intercept) 19.7            NaN         NaN         NaN
18  cyl         NA          NA          NA          NA
19  hp          NA          NA          NA          NA
20  wt          NA          NA          NA          NA
21  (Intercept) 15          NaN         NaN         NaN
22  cyl         NA          NA          NA          NA
23  hp          NA          NA          NA          NA
24  wt          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

what I want is a table that looks like this:

```
carb    intercept   cyl         hp          wt
1   46.034633   2.650503624 -0.230007961    -5.231999683
2   39.84451509 -0.846094229    -0.007452737    -4.133340298
3   17.50267062 NA          NA          -0.3115727
4   45.33390978 -4.195214198    0.029361878 -1.239041102
6   19.7            NA          NA          NA
8   15          NA          NA          NA
```

I don't know how to bring the value of the grouping variable in. If I can get that added to what I already have I know how to transpose the data into the form I need.

I am updating a bit, as an answer here gave me what I wanted, but is causing an error that I can't seem to fix. the solution uses lmList from the nlme library. The code I am using is this

```
fit <- lmList(SentLength~Unified_UPPER+Unified_LOWER+GRADE | SentType, data=df, na.omit)
```

```
and this is the data I am running it on:
SentType    SentLength  Unified_UPPER   Unified_LOWER   GRADE
Jail        0.06578947  0.06666667      0.06666667      3
Other       0           6               0               4
Other       0           6               6               1
Probation   6           0               0               1
Other       0           9               0               6
Jail        1.41447368  6               0               3
Probation   6           0               0               1
Probation   6           0               0               1
Probation   12          0               0               2
Jail        6           16              6               6
Prison      36          27              21              5
Probation   24          9               0               6
Jail        0.23026316  0.5             0               1
Jail        0.09868421  0.06666667      0.06666667      1
Probation   60          27              21              6
Probation   6           1               0               1
Probation   24          0               0               3
Prison      36          54              36              8
Probation   24          9               0               6
Probation   6           0               0               1
Probation   0           0.06666667      0.06666667      1
Probation   24          0               0               3
Jail        0.13157895  1               0.06666667      1
Jail        0.09868421  1               0.1             1
Prison      42          60              48              8
Probation   6           0               0               2
Other       0           0               0               1
Prison      6           6               6               1
Prison      6           6               6               1
Other       0           16              9               7
```

I get this error:
Error in na.fail.default(data) : missing values in object
despite no missing values in the data. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: That's a fairly data approach. I'd recommend using `group_map`, which is part of `dplyr`, instead of `split %>% map %>% map_df`. If you look at the bottom of the `?group_map` help page, the 3rd example, commented as "a list of tibbles", is pretty much exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It always amazes me that people insist on using tidyverse mumbo-jumbo for this when it is so incredibly easy with package nlme, which is a "recommended package", meaning it should be part of your R installation and you don't even need to install it.

```
library(nlme)
fit <- lmList(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt | carb, data = mtcars)
coef(fit)
#  (Intercept)        cyl           hp         wt
#1    46.03463  2.6505036 -0.230007961 -5.2319997
#2    39.84452 -0.8460942 -0.007452737 -4.1333403
#3    17.50267         NA           NA -0.3115727
#4    45.33391 -4.1952142  0.029361878 -1.2390411
#6    19.70000         NA           NA         NA
#8    15.00000         NA           NA         NA
```

Note that the row names are the `carb` values.

There is also a `summary` method producing convenient output. However, read `help("summary.lmList")` regarding the `pool` parameter if you use it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe I have never heard of this package before, and you were right about it already being installed. Thank you!

Comment: So I may have jumped the gun a bit. When I use this on my actual data, I get an error: Error in na.fail.default(data) : missing values in object   despite there being no NA in the data. I tried using na.omit but still get the error. Any idea what is going on? I was able to get a small portion of my data into a form that I can share and I am updating the question to include it.

Comment: Please share data as the output of `dput(yourdata)`. That said, your data looks strange. Why do you have so many duplicated and integer values in `SentLength`? Your dependent variable looks like assumptions of OLS linear regression might be violated.

Comment: I am fairly certain that I am violating assumptions (the UPPER and LOWER variables are definitely correlated), but to make a long story short, for the purposes of what I am doing I am being told not to worry about them. The data I have shared is a very small subset of what I am actually working with, and it is possible that the randomization I did just pulled a chunk that is somewhat homogenous.

Comment: I have been tinkering with this and just figured out a solution. If I use na.exclude instead of na.omit, it works. I have no idea why that fixes it, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Use `summarise` with `unnest_wider`:

```
df %>%
   summarise(a = list(coef(lm(mpg~cyl + hp + wt, cur_data()))), .by = carb)%>%
   unnest_wider(a, names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 6 × 5
   carb `a_(Intercept)`  a_cyl     a_hp   a_wt
  <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4            45.3 -4.20   0.0294  -1.24 
2     1            46.0  2.65  -0.230   -5.23 
3     2            39.8 -0.846 -0.00745 -4.13 
4     3            17.5 NA     NA       -0.312
5     6            19.7 NA     NA       NA    
6     8            15   NA     NA       NA
```

#### EFFICIENT WAY IN BASE R

Seems you are only interested in the coefficients. In base R you could do:

```
mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb)
a <- coef(lm(mpg~ carb/(cyl+hp+wt) + 0, mtcars))
a
       carb1        carb2        carb3        carb4        carb6        carb8    carb1:cyl 
46.034632999 39.844515085 17.502670623 45.333909777 19.700000000 15.000000000  2.650503624 
   carb2:cyl    carb3:cyl    carb4:cyl    carb6:cyl    carb8:cyl     carb1:hp     carb2:hp 
-0.846094229           NA -4.195214198           NA           NA -0.230007961 -0.007452737 
    carb3:hp     carb4:hp     carb6:hp     carb8:hp     carb1:wt     carb2:wt     carb3:wt 
          NA  0.029361878           NA           NA -5.231999683 -4.133340298 -0.311572700 
    carb4:wt     carb6:wt     carb8:wt 
-1.239041102           NA           NA
```

The coefficients above matches the coefficients you have. You can easily transform to matrix:

```
matrix(a, nlevels(mtcars$carb))
         [,1]       [,2]         [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 46.03463  2.6505036 -0.230007961 -5.2319997
[2,] 39.84452 -0.8460942 -0.007452737 -4.1333403
[3,] 17.50267         NA           NA -0.3115727
[4,] 45.33391 -4.1952142  0.029361878 -1.2390411
[5,] 19.70000         NA           NA         NA
[6,] 15.00000         NA           NA         NA
```

Which looks like yours but without names. In the naming part, if you know regular expressions, it is easy as you can directly get the names from the vector a

```
dm <- list(unique(sub(":.*", "", names(a))),
           replace(unique(gsub(".*:|.*\\d+", "", names(a))), 1, 'intercepy'))
matrix(a,  nlevels(mtcars$carb), dimnames = dm)
      intercepy        cyl           hp         wt
carb1  46.03463  2.6505036 -0.230007961 -5.2319997
carb2  39.84452 -0.8460942 -0.007452737 -4.1333403
carb3  17.50267         NA           NA -0.3115727
carb4  45.33391 -4.1952142  0.029361878 -1.2390411
carb6  19.70000         NA           NA         NA
carb8  15.00000         NA           NA         NA
```

---

Suppose you do not know regex, then use `split`:

```
b <- mtcars$carb
d <- split(a, rep(levels(b), nlevels(b), length=length(a)))
array2DF(structure(d, dim = nlevels(b)))

 Var1    carb1  carb1:cyl     carb1:hp   carb1:wt
1    1 46.03463  2.6505036 -0.230007961 -5.2319997
2    2 39.84452 -0.8460942 -0.007452737 -4.1333403
3    3 17.50267         NA           NA -0.3115727
4    4 45.33391 -4.1952142  0.029361878 -1.2390411
5    6 19.70000         NA           NA         NA
6    8 15.00000         NA           NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach (taking advantage of `nest`ing data and the fact that one can stuff complex structures like models, plots etc. into a dataframe's cell by enclosing them into a `list`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars |>
  nest_by(carb) |>
  transmute(coeffs = lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + wt, data) |>
              coef() |>
              list() ## !
            ) |>
  unnest_wider(coeffs)
```

```
## + # A tibble: 6 x 5
##    carb `(Intercept)`    cyl       hp     wt
##   <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1     1          46.0  2.65  -0.230   -5.23 
## 2     2          39.8 -0.846 -0.00745 -4.13 
## 3     3          17.5 NA     NA       -0.312
## 4     4          45.3 -4.20   0.0294  -1.24 
## 5     6          19.7 NA     NA       NA    
## 6     8          15   NA     NA       NA
```